# Circular Induction

Tags: proof-verification, logic, induction, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

**Question:** Suppose you have
a circle with equal numbers of 0’s and 1’s on it’s boundary, there is
some point I can start at such that if and travel clockwise around the
boundary from that point, I will never see more 1’s than 0’s.

**Where I am at:** 
I know since there are equal numbers of 0’s and 1’s there must be an even number of points on the boundary. that is k = 2j, for some j integer.

**Where I get Stuck:**
I dont understand how to use induction to show there will never be more 1s than 0s.

Comment: Hint: with a fixed orientation on your circle, find a $1$ that is immediately followed by a $0$, remove them both, and use the induction hypothesis with the same orientation.

Comment: @Mindlack just wondering why does it have to be a 1 followed by a 0 and not another pair?